# How to check if user has permissions to see View definitions on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

How to find if the logged in User has permissions to see "view" definitions on SQL Server?  I need to find out what tables/columns a view is made from,

I used this SQL for the same; for view definition, we used this query:

Query:

```
select * 
from sys.objects 
where name like '%SECTION_MASTER_V%'
```

Result:  579337674

Query:

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.object_id = 579337674
  AND o.type = 'V'
```

Result: **null**

I get null as a result. Does anyone knows what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can see object-level permissions using this query: the commented-out section in the `WHERE` clause will limit the results to the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission.

```
SELECT 
    o.name AS ObjectName,
    su.name AS LoginName,
    dp.permission_name AS PermissionType,
    dp.state_desc AS PermissionStatus
FROM 
    sys.database_permissions dp
     INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON 
        dp.major_id = o.object_id
     INNER JOIN 
    sys.sysusers su ON 
        dp.grantee_principal_id = su.uid
--WHERE dp.[type] = 'vw'
ORDER BY o.name
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get null as a result. Does anyone knows what may be wrong here?

You need the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission, otherwise you get an empty result set.

Use can use [`sys.fn_my_permissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql) or [`HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-perms-by-name-transact-sql) to get the relevant permission on a database for the current user:

##### HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME:

```sql
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, 'DATABASE', 'VIEW DEFINITION');
```

You get a simple `0` or `1` as a result of this query.

##### sys.fn_my_permissions

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE') 
WHERE permission_name = N'VIEW DEFINITION'
```

The result set for this query looks like this:

| entity_name | subentity_name | permission_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| database |  | VIEW DEFINITION |

##### With impersonation

If you have the `IMPERSONATE` permission, you can even check it for another user:

```sql
EXECUTE AS USER = 'otheruser'
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, 'DATABASE', 'VIEW DEFINITION');  
REVERT
```

*or*

```sql
EXECUTE AS USER = 'otheruser';
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE')
WHERE permission_name = N'VIEW DEFINITION'
REVERT
```

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

1. Use sp_helptext: it's a lot easier than jumping through system tables.
2. You can use sys.fn_my_permissions to see what permissions you have on any object.